# How to save Scroll position of a nestedScroll view

Tags: flutter, dart

I saved scroll postion of customScrollView but I can't save scrollPosition of a NestedScroll View and It seems some tricky.

In my app I have a bottomNavigationBar and in one of its tab I have a nested Scroll View with 3 tabs
and in nestedScrollView's headerSliverBuilder I have a sliverAppBar and I want to save tab and tab scroll position when I swipe between tabs and bottomNavigationBar Items.

is there any way to do this?

```dart
NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[_sliverAppBar()];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              _gridView(category: _albums),
              _gridView(category: _artists),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using a separate widget for the nestedScrollView that saves its position when it is unmounted and loads it again on initState